# What's the best way to track changes to a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I would like my Django app to track any changes to a model whenever a person changes it. So if the name element of a user model changes I'd like to save the following:

-The elements being changed

-The elements' values before the change

-The elements' values after the change

I'm wondering if there's a plugin for Django that makes this easy. Apologies in advance if this is a newbie question.

Comment: Check out https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/

Answer (score 2):

You can track values changes with built-in model signals, like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.